# Does anyone know how to fix boto.exception.SWFResponseError: SWFResponseError: 400 Bad Request on AWS GovCloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto, amazon-swf

I am trying to register a domain on SWF using boto. But it's throwing me this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "register.py", line 17, in <module>
    swf_entity.register()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/swf/layer2.py", line 67, in register
    self.description)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/swf/layer1.py", line 827, in register_domain
    'description': description,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/swf/layer1.py", line 118, in json_request
    return self.make_request(action, json_input, object_hook)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/swf/layer1.py", line 145, in make_request
    raise excp_cls(response.status, response.reason, body=json_body)
boto.exception.SWFResponseError: SWFResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The security token included in the request is invalid.', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#UnrecognizedClientException'}
```

Also, In CLI.

aws swf list-domains --registration-status REGISTERED

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='swf.swf.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fae9bafd9b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Everything is working perfectly on other AWS region. But it not working in AWS GovCloud (US) Region.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add region in boto config file like as

```
[SWF]
region = us-gov-west-1
```

Comment: Add some more description

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware your regular AWS credentials will not work in GovCloud? It is a separate account and has totally different credentials.

Assuming you are indeed using the correct credentials, the SWF endpoint you (or Boto) is connecting to is incorrect. It is connecting to `swf.swf.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com.amazonaws.com` instead of `swf.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com`

```
$ host swf.swf.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com.amazonaws.com
Host swf.swf.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com.amazonaws.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ host swf.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
swf.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com has address 205.251.239.72
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. CLI is Working. But boto SWF is not working.   boto.exception.SWFResponseError: SWFResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The security token included in the request is invalid.', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#UnrecognizedClientException'}